# Drools stuck firing always the same rule

Tags: drools

For some reason, drools get stuck in a loop firing always the same rule, with the same arguments ($c and $d).

```
rule removing_invalid_dungeons
    when
    $c : Cave()
    $d : Dungeon(valid, x < $c.minCoordinateHorizontal || x > $c.maxCoordinateHorizontal || y<$c.minCoordinateVertical || y>$c.maxCoordinateVertical)
then
    Agent.logger.info("Rule fired ["+drools.getRule().getName()+"] - {}",$d.toString());
    modify($d) {setValid(false)};
    modify($c){removeDungeon($d)};
    retract($d);    
end;
```

I put a breakpoint and I could see that after the first time it fires, it keeps firing even with valid==false! Even worse, $d has been retracted.

If I remove the modify($c), it works, firing only one time.

```
rule removing_invalid_dungeons
when
    $c : Cave()
    $d : Dungeon(valid, x < $c.minCoordinateHorizontal || x > $c.maxCoordinateHorizontal || y<$c.minCoordinateVertical || y>$c.maxCoordinateVertical)
then
    Agent.logger.info("Rule fired ["+drools.getRule().getName()+"] - {}",$d.toString());
    modify($d) {setValid(false)};
    $c.removeDungeon($d);
    retract($d);    
end;
```

I debugged and $c.removeDungeon($d) is working properly (it just removes $d from a list).

Why? Any clue?

Comment: I don't believe that this is the full story. If you retract $d then there's no way the rule should fire again unless you have other Dungeons around . Then it'll fire until all Dungeons are gone. - Provide the full code for reproducing the problem, i.e., the facts you construct and insert, and other rules that might fire. (Is there a rule that *creates and inserts* Dungeons?)

Comment: Full code is big. I do not want to delegate to you my job :-) how do I dump all facts of the working memory to debug? All rules have a logger.info and console shows that no other rule are being fired.

Comment: Can you post the construction and insertion of a set of Cave and Dungeon facts to recreate the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the problem with a smaller subset of rules or in a way that is easier to share. I'll go to the bottom of this. If I find the solution I will post here, if not, I will try posting the complete code of a smaller subset.

Comment: You should also have a constraint `$d: Dungeon(...) Cave( dungeons contains $d )`. Perhaps better than the geometric constraint that the Dungeon is outside the (bounding rectangle of) the Cave.